# Create mongoose queries with Array parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem to build query

Users select regions, languages, and roles.
User can select one, two or all three roles.

Now how I should finde lobby where is an empty slot for user?

```js
const lobby = Lobby.findOne({ region: region})
          .where('languages').in(languages)
```

My schema looks like this:

```html
const lobby = new Schema ({

languages: [{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }], 

region: {
    type:String,
    required: true
},

guardian:{
    default:null,
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Users",
    },
support:{
    default:null,
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Users",
},
dps:{
    default:null,
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Users",
},
```

Comment: Are you sure you import your schema `Lobby` to the document you have your query? It seems that the code can't find `Lobby` schema.

Comment: Yes. Everything works well, I can find a lobby but now I need to solve a problem how to check if there is an empty slot for user roles